# How to display list of images in ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android. I want to display the list of images using the ListView. The images which are displayed are decided at runtime according to server response. and also i want to embedd some text on this image(like match scoring chip). the number of images are not fix. Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1):

I would read the 6 parts to this series. It will show you how to create your own custom listview rows to accomplish what you are asking for:
http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/

Comment: Since that blog post series is a bit old, I have a more current edition of the same material available in a PDF: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf